# When will MeteorJS authentication be in place?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

It has been asked when MeteorJS will have auth in place... I think everyone is anxious to hear back on this for such a fantastic platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the branch author they just finished up the first chunk today and are ready for input / testing:

### https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Getting-started-with-Auth

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get started with what's already there you can use [Meteorite](http://oortcloud.github.com/meteorite/) and create a project using the `auth` branch of Meteor with:

```
mrt create newappname --branch auth
```

Then you can see how to add various authentication schemes and render pre-generated templates  for allowing users to log in by reading through the Meteor Wiki here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Getting-started-with-Auth

For example, you get a template that provides the whole login button with form by placing something like `{{> loginButtons}}` into one of your templates.

Remember that the implementation may still change and you'll want to switch your app back to `master` once `auth` gets merged in at a later stage to keep things more up-to-date. There are apps out there using `auth` and they work fine. For an example, see [Atmosphere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com).